# Manipulate with a variable number of sliders

Tags: manipulate, slider

I have a function that operates on a **list of parameters of variable-length** $n$.  I would like to create a `Manipulate[]` that has $n$ sliders, one for each list element, each considered a separate parameter. The syntax `Manipulate[expr,{u,...},{v,...},...]]` does not lend itself to this, as it is geared toward a **fixed number of parameters** known in advance, and referenced by separate variable names.

I have started exploring preparing a list of arguments to `Manipulate[]` and then using `Apply[]`, but this seems tricky and complicated.

*Anyone come upon this conundrum before?*

Comment: See a [related SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521679/mathematica-dynamic-number-of-menus/8522943#8522943).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) in *Mathematica* documentation has the following example that looks like what you need.

```
DynamicModule[{n = 5, data = Table[RandomReal[], {20}]},
Column[{
Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 20, 1}],
Dynamic[Grid[Table[With[{i = i},
   {Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], Dynamic[data[[i]]]}], {i, n}]
 ]]}]]
```

[image: nested sliders]

It builds a list of controllers (`Slider`-s in this particular case) by using the fact that you can assign values to not just symbols but also to members of a list by doing `data[[1]] = value`. Which is exactly the thing that happens inside `Dynamic[data[[i]]]`, as it is equivalent to:

```
Dynamic[data[[i]], (data[[i]] = #)&]
```

telling *Mathematica* to whenever the actual value of `data[[i]]` is changed, use the new value (`#`) to update the expression `data[[i]]`.

Also from the Documentation Center, the last example in [Manipulate: Neat Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate&lang=en) may be useful:

```
Manipulate[
ArrayPlot[
Take[data, h, w]], {{data, RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 20}]}, 
ControlType -> None}, {{h, 5}, 1, 10, 1}, {{w, 5}, 1, 20, 1}, 
Dynamic[Panel[
 Grid[Outer[Checkbox[Dynamic[data[[#1, #2]]], {0, 1}] &, Range[h], 
 Range[w]]]]]]
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful---Thanks so much!

Comment: @Joseph, glad the link was helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a followup to my question, code based on the example provided by kguler.
Note there is no longer any need for `Manipulate[]`— it is all handled by `Dynamic[]`.

```
data = Table[RandomReal[], {5}];

DynamicModule[ {n = Length[data]},

 Column[{

   Dynamic[
    Grid[
     Table[
      With[{i = i},
       {i,
        Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]],
        Dynamic[data[[i]]]
        }
       ],
      {i, n}
      ](*Table*)
     ]],(*Dynamic*)

   Dynamic[ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]]

   }, Center](*Column*)
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is similar to kguler's solution, but it assumes that there is a more complex updating going on during slider-interaction (namely, both `list` and `total` are updated), to illustrate more realistic cases where a single `Dynamic` object might affect more than one variables. Also it shows how to use `Map` with a variable number of `Slider`-s. For localization and elegance, the whole code should be wrapped into `DynamicModule`, but since this is not the point here, I omitted.

```
update[n_] := (list = Table[0, {n}]; total = Total@list); (* function called when n is changed *)

n = 5;
update[n]; (* initialize list and total *)

Slider[Dynamic[n, (n = #; update[#]) &], {1, 10, 1}]

Dynamic[total]

Dynamic[Grid[
  {
   #,
   Slider[Dynamic[list[[#]], 
       Function[{x}, list[[#]] = x; total = Total@list]], {0, 1}], 
   Dynamic[list[[#]]]
  } & /@ Range[n]
  ], TrackedSymbols :> {n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]