# How to programmatically create a Manipulate in another Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

Background: the following Manipulate works as expected

```
 db := {{1, 10, 11}, {2, 20, 21}, {3, 5, 11}, {4, 15, 11}, {5, 8, 21}};
 Manipulate[
   Manipulate[ {a, 1, db[[x, 2]]}, {a, 1, db[[x, 2]]}],
 {{x, 1}, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Now I want to make the inner-Manipulate more flexible... I tried this:

```
 Manipulate[
   Manipulate[s, {a, 1, db[[x, 2]]}] /. s -> {a, 1, db[[x, 2]]},
 {{x, 1}, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Where s is supposed to be entirely variable based on some value in the outer-Manipulate, but it fails.

Question: I want to programmatically build a(n inner-)Manipulate from values selected in an (outer-)Manipulate. Is this possible, if so how?

UPDATE:
I modified Piilsy's answer so that it works as follows:

```
 Manipulate[
  Manipulate[
    Column[Table[{##}[[i, 1, 1]], {i, 1, Length[{##}]}]], ##] 
    & @@Table[{{x[i], 0.5}, 0, 1}, {i, 1, n}], 
 {n, Range[6]}]
```

**Question:Can this code be enhanced, i.e. made clearer?**

Comment: Can you explain why the first variant where you entered `{a, 1, db[[x, 2]]}` literally won't work for your application?

Comment: The inner-manipulate can have a variable number of controls depending on the outer.

Comment: Colors, in fact. A geometry file is read from a database the number of faces is determined and then a color changing manipulate is ( supposed to be ) set up.

Comment: @ndroock1 I've updated my answer so that the sliders work properly, and have taken a stab at explaining what went wrong.

Comment: Just in case you have not already seen: [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199/125) and several answers therein.

Comment: @kguler - I had not, thanks for the reference!

Comment: Nasser M. Abassi had posted an interesting answer about a similar question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8632036/884752

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT** to make the sliders work, in response to comments:

Here's one possible solution, wrapping your inner `Manipulate` in `With` statement that defines both the thing that you want to manipulate, and the `Sequence` of controls, like so:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   value    = Column[Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]],
   controls = Sequence @@ Table[{{x[i], 0.5}, 0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]},
  Manipulate[
   value,
   controls]],
 {n, Range[6]}]
```

Both `value` and `controls` need to be defined in the same place because `Manipulate`, like some other constructs (including `Module`, `Function` and `RuleDelayed`) does some sort of symbol renaming for expressions inside of it, and you need the `x` in `value` to be the same `x` in `controls`.

This gives you a setup that looks like this:

[image: nested Manipulates]

If you try it out in a notebook, you will have `n` sliders in the inner `Manipulate`.

Comment: Did not work at first but it was because I had an x defined elsewhere in my session, looks good. Will try to complete it.

Comment: Piilsy - But x[i] is displayed instead of the value, have you noticed?

Comment: Nice job! , Pillsy. This is a flexible multi-level, multi-variable Manipulate setup. Thank you.