# How to control variables of outer and inner Manipulates?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

Consider the following ( working ) snippet:

```
  Manipulate[
   Column[{
    Manipulate[
     vote,
     {vote, {"Yes", "No"}},
     Initialization :> {votes = 0}
    ],
    k,
    Button["TEST", Print[votes]]
   }],
   {k, 1, 5, .5}
  ]
```

My question concerns programming style and Outer/Inner Manipulate structures. What is the best way to handle code that is executed conditionally based on values in the inner Manipulate, but needs to be processed further in the outer Manipulate? I.e. checking thresholds, maintaining sub-totals, balancing, etc.

To make my question 'answerable' I have translated it in terms of a simplified example: **how / where would you maintain a Yes vote counter that is used in the outer manipulate?**

UPDATE:
The requested pattern would also apply to synchronizing views in data on Tabs on a TabView.

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect the actual problem here, please feel free to revert/change if you think it is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer `Manipulate` defines a list (`voteList`) for tracking all votes (thus I used integer values for `k`), and the inner `Manipulate` is using the actual value of the k<sup>th</sup> vote for the definition of `vote`. If the inner Yes/No setter is changed, it changes `vote`, `voteList` and the number of `votes` as well, due to the pure controlfunction `SetterBar`. I also moved the initialization code to the outer `Manipulate`, as votes should be local to the whole thing, not just the inner `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   Manipulate[
    vote,
    {{vote, voteList[[k]]}, {True, False}, 
     SetterBar[
       Dynamic[vote, (vote = #; voteList[[k]] = #; 
          votes = Total@Boole@voteList) &], {True -> "Yes", 
        False -> "No"}] &}
    ],
   (*voteList,*)
   Button["Votes: " <> ToString@votes, Print[votes]]
   }],
 {k, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {voteList, ControlType -> None},
 {votes, ControlType -> None},
 Initialization :> {votes = 0, voteList = Table[False, {5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course in this example of yours there is no need to wrap the internal `vote` into `Manipulate`, but I guess that this was just a toy example of a more complex problem. I'm not sure my solution is eaxactly the thing you are looking for, but if you provide some feedback, I can modify the code to better fit your requirements.

Comment: This is just fine, Istvan. I have learned so much about Manipulate on this site. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to read on how to link dynamic controllers e.g. here: [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders).