# How can one popup menu be used to add another?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, interface

I'm trying to construct a GUI that changes depending on what's chosen in certain popup menu's.  For example:  The default state of the menu is condition one, but when the first PopupMenu is selected other menu configurations are displayed. To keep the GUI simple each popup menu has a function attached and the menu change allows the user to use a different set of functions. Data input is done by importing so non of these menus provide variable input to functions.  I have reviewed this code:  [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders) but have not been able to figure out how to modify it to produce the results I need.  Thanks very much for your help!  Bad code example follows:

```
DynamicModule[{n = 1}, 
Column[{Dynamic[
Grid[Table[
  With[{i = i}, {i, 
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[data[[i]]], {a -> "one menu" , 
      b -> "Add another Menu" }], Dynamic[data[[i]]]}], {i, 
   n}](*Table*)]](*Dynamic*)}, Center](*Column*)]
```

I would like the menu to produce a second menu when "Add another Menu" is selected. So for example "Add another menu" is selected and it produces a "New Menu" Popup Menu below it, but remains showing the "Add another menu" selection and does not revert back to "one menu".

Comment: Ok, now I saw that I was way off in your intentions

Comment: @Rojo no prob, In the future I'll try and post a better example. Thanks!

Comment: @Rojo your answer had been deleted but just to follow up -- I am not rejecting the use of tagging rules per se -- I use them often -- just noting that they can be a bottleneck if you have a lot of them and it wasn't clear how big E Halls actual GUI is -- so worth the caveat.

Comment: Mike, I had totally misinterpreted his question, my bad. I thought he wanted a separate dialog in which to choose from certain functions that would be available to him in another separate dialog. Somehow I read popup and thought dialog. So, I thought that if I used dynamic module wormholes, I would still need the generating notebook to link those dialogs...

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, forgot to ping you in the previous comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's see if now I got it better...

```
DynamicModule[{var = False}, 
Dynamic@Column[{PopupMenu[ 
Dynamic[var], {False -> #, 
True -> "Add another Menu"}],   
If[var, #0["new menu"], ## &[]]}]] &["one menu"]
```

Comment: +1 for `#0` and `##&[]` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I already used him once earlier today, which is weird because I never use it, check [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5201124#5201124).

Comment: @Rojo nicely done! Thanks!

Comment: One more thing to add to the *long* list of code samples I need to work through.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the chat thing is not worth it. I just found it interesting that I ended up with a suboptimal solution that was particularly obfuscated and weird. I think I woke up with #0 and patterns in my mind today

Comment: But this one is nice :), I couldn't have done it without you guys ,`#0` and `##&[]`

Comment: @Rojo actually that makes it of interest to me; after all "I code perverse *Mathematica*" according to Simon.

Comment: ditto +1 for #0 and ##&[]

Comment: @Rojo,  How can this code be extended so that when the "Add another menu" pulldown is selected, the new pulldown is visible in the form of "New Menu", and the first pulldown still shows "Add another menu"?  Thanks!

Comment: @RHall, I didn't understand. What do you want the options of the new pulldown menu to be?

Comment: @Rojo see my edits above  Thank you!

Comment: So you basically want this same behaviour but, in all but the frist menu, to replace "one menu" by "new menu"? If so, you could pass it as a parameter, like `DynamicModule[{var = False}, 
   Dynamic@Column[{PopupMenu[
       Dynamic[var], {False -> #, True -> "Add another Menu"}], 
      If[var, #0["new menu"], ## &[]]}]] &["one menu"]`

Comment: @RHall, if you confirm I'll edit my answer, or you feel free to edit it for me

Comment: @Rojo, Exactly right thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Some generic examples:

```
DynamicModule[{var = 3, var2 = 1, var3 = "hello"},

 Column[{
   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[var], {1 -> "Display Popup", 2 -> "Display Input field", 
     3 -> "None"}],

   PaneSelector[{
     1 -> PopupMenu[Dynamic[var2], Range[4]],
     2 -> InputField[Dynamic[var3]],
     3 -> Spacer[0]
     }, Dynamic[var]]

   }]
 ]
```

Alternatively use `Join` and `If` | `Switch` | `Which` to determine what gets displayed:

```
DynamicModule[{var = 3, var2 = 1, var3 = "hello"},

 Dynamic[
  Column[
   Join[
    {PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[var], {1 -> "Display Popup", 2 -> "Display Input field",
        3 -> "None"}]},

    Switch[var,
     1, {PopupMenu[Dynamic[var2], Range[4]]},
     2, {InputField[Dynamic[var3]]},
     3, {}
     ]
    ]

   ],
  TrackedSymbols :> {var}]
 ]
```

And you can set other variables based on what gets chosen in your "starting" popup e.g.:

```
PopupMenu[
 Dynamic[var, (var = #; If[var==1,var2 = 2; var3 = "something"]) &], {1 -> 
   "Display Popup", 2 -> "Display Input field", 3 -> "None"}]
```

Comment: Very cool solution Mike. Works great! Thanks for the help!