# Create Manipulate with a variable number of controls

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I would like to create Manipulate which look like this

```
n = 4;
Manipulate[{a, b, c}, {a, Range[n]}, {b, Range[n]}, {c, Range[n]}]
```

but wherein list of controls defined dynamically. I tried this code, which does not work

```
vars = {a, b, c};
Manipulate[vars, Table[{vars[[i]], Range[n]}, {i, 1, vars // Length}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Manipulate` to `Evaluate` the expression generating the controls before the rest.
Also you have to convert the single `List` generated by `Table` into a sequence of lists, each one specifying a single controller.
For example with:

```
vars = {a, b, c};
n = 4;
Manipulate[
 Evaluate@vars,
 Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ Table[{vars[[i]], Range[n]}, {i, 1, vars // Length}]
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Generalizing to a variable number of controls and variable range of controls.

```
maxNbrControls = 10;
maxRngControls = 10;

Manipulate[
 Manipulate[
  Evaluate[
   a /@ Range[nbrControls]],
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ ({{a[#], 1, Subscript[a, #]},
        Range[rngControls],
        ControlType -> SetterBar} & /@
      Range[nbrControls])]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{nbrControls, 3, "Number of\nControls"},
     Range[maxNbrControls]}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{rngControls, 4, "Range of\nControls"},
     Range[maxRngControls]}]}]]
```

[image]