# Generation of Sliders via Tables/For loops

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I have a list named data that contains lists of arbitrary size,

```
data={{0.5, 0.5}, {}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
```

I now want to generate for each sub-list the appropriate number of sliders (for the empty sets none, <strike>though I believe they are easy to skip</strike>). However, I am not sure if this is even possible.

In my quest I stumbled upon this thread, [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders), which allows me to generate sliders for one sub-list,

```
Dynamic[Grid[
Table[With[{i = i}, {Slider[Dynamic[data[[1]][[i]]]], 
 Dynamic[data[[1]][[i]]]}], {i, Length[data[[1]]]}]]]
```

This works perfectly fine if I use a constant as an index for `data`, in this case 1.

However, if I want to extend this by using a for loop or a table to make that index variable, say

```
Table[Dynamic[Grid[
Table[With[{i = i}, {Slider[Dynamic[data[[k]][[i]]]], 
 Dynamic[data[[k]][[i]]]}], {i, Length[data[[k]]]}]]],{k,1,1}]
```

the `k` gets marked red and the code fails. Is it even possible to generate sliders this way? I imagine the reason that the code fails is that Dynamic requires the object under consideration to remain constant, but is there a way around this?

Comment: What does the numbers in the sublists represent?

Comment: Probabilities which exist for some variables but not for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be something like this would work:

```
   data2 = Select[data, Length@# > 1 &];

Dynamic[Column@
  Flatten@Table[
    With[{i = i, k = k}, {Slider[Dynamic[data2[[k]][[i]]]], 
      Dynamic[data2[[k]][[i]]]}], {k, 1, Length@data2, 1}, {i, 1, 
     Length@data2[[k]]}]]
```

Second option:
To work directly with data you can try this:

```
 data = {{0.5, 0.5}, {}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}};
 index = Complement[Range[Length@data], Position[data, {}] // Flatten];

Dynamic[Column@
  Flatten@Table[
    With[{i = i, k = k}, {Slider[Dynamic[data[[k]][[i]]]], 
      Dynamic[data[[k]][[i]]]}], {k, index}, {i, 1, 
     Length@data[[k]]}]]
```

Comment: Is there a way for the sliders to change the values in the original data, not data2? Apart from that it is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @hpschrei I have added what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!