# Side by side sliders

Tags: gui-construction

In this question [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/manipulate-with-a-variable-number-of-sliders) one of the answer is

```
DynamicModule[{n = 5, data = Table[RandomReal[], {20}]}, 
 Column[{Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 20, 1}], 
   Dynamic[Grid[
     Table[With[{i = i}, {Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], 
        Dynamic[data[[i]]]}], {i, n}]]]}]]
```

Unfortunately the sliders are developped up to down and I wonder if there is a way to develop them side by side or positionned in a matrix.

Here is the normal behavior

---s---

---s1---

---s2---

---s3---

which after expansion will give

---s---
   ---s1---

---s2---

---s3---

---s4---

---s5---
       .
       .
       .

I want --- because it takes less space

---s---
   ---s1---     ---s3---

---s2---     ---s4---

---s5---         .

```
   .            .    

   .            . 

   .            .
```

and why not with 3 or more columns

Comment: Have you tried to play with `Column/Grid` used there?

Comment: Yes without success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer to the question **after** editing

You can use [`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html) to automatically format elements of a list arranged in a grid of many columns.

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  n = 5,
  data = Table[RandomReal[], {20}]
  },
 Column[
  {
   Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 20, 1}],
   Dynamic[
    Multicolumn[
     Table[
      With[{i = i}, 
       Column[{Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], Dynamic[data[[i]]]}]], {i, 
       n}]
     , 3]
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Answer to the question **before** editing

Change [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html) for [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html). [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) the table.

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  n = 5
  , data = Table[RandomReal[], {20}]
  },
 Row[
  {
   Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 20, 1}],
   Dynamic[
    Grid[Transpose@Table[
       With[{i = i}, {Slider[Dynamic[data[[i]]]], Dynamic[data[[i]]]}]
       , {i, n}]
     ]
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope to have been clearer

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki, doe this answer the new question? In the future, please explain what you need in the question in detail from the beginning. If you then realize you need something different, ask another question.  Read [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397).  Now, let's do a clean up of the obsolete comments.