# Plot inside Manipulate with indexed coefficients fails

Tags: plotting, manipulate, polynomials

I am trying to plot a polynomial inside `Manipulate` with indexed coefficients.

Surprisingly, only an empty plot is generated.

Any help welcome.

```
Block[{n = 3},
 Manipulate @@ {
 Column[{
  Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, n}],
  Plot[Evaluate@Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, n}], {x, -5, 5}]
 }],
 Sequence @@ Table[{{a[i], 0}, -2, 2}, {i, 0, n}]
}]
```

Regards
Robert

Comment: Why are you using `Manipulate @@`?  Because of this the `Plot[...]` evaluates early and `Manipulate` will never see the `Plot` command.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am using Manipulate @@ to have an programmable number n of adjustable coefficients.

Comment: Closely related: [Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199/5478)

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is not easy.  Both evaluation control and symbol localization can be tricky in Mathematica, and your code has subtle errors related to both.

First I will give a possible solution, then I will discuss the problems with your approach.

```
manip[n_] :=
 Block[{a,x}, (* prevent conflict with any global a, x *)
   With[{
     vars = Sequence @@ Table[{{a[i], 0}, -2, 2}, {i, 0, n}],
     poly = Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, n}]
     },
    Manipulate[
     Column[{
       poly,
       Plot[poly, {x, -5, 5}]
       }],
     vars
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

Problems with your code:

- Using `Manipulate @@ {...}` instead of `Manipulate[...]` prevents the `HoldAll` attribute of `Manipulate` from taking effect.  You probably did this on purpose to allow the second argument to evaluate.  But the first one evaluates too, including the `Plot` part. `Manipulate` will never have a chance to see the `Plot` command (only its empty result).
- `Block` sets `n` only temporarily. This means that after evaluating the content of `Block`, the result must not contain any unevaluated `n` symbols.  If it does, these will never get the value `3` again.  This is in contradiction with the requirement not to evaluate `Plot` ...
- When compound expressions are used as `Manipulate` variables, i.e. `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ..., they will internally be replaced by single symbols.  In practice this means that each of `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ... must appear explicitly in the body of `Manipulate`.  `a[i]`, with `i` being substituted only during dynamic evaluation, will not work.

These difficulties are overcome by pre-generating both the variable list and the polynomial, and injecting them into a `Manipulate`.

Another note: Usually people recommend against using `Subscript[a,1]` instead of `a[1]`.  I think in this case it's quite safe to use the subscript, as the computation will be done with replacement symbols anyway.  The `Manipulate` interface will look better.

Comment: nice, thx. The problem with this kind of stuff is always that one knows well what is desired but it is difficult to tell MMA. Wouldn't it be easier to generate the code as a String and convert to an expression?

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't do it with `Manipulate[]`, so I used pure `Dynamic[]` constructs instead:

```
With[{nmax = 12},
     DynamicModule[{n = 3, cofs = ConstantArray[0, 4]},
                   Panel[Row[{Column[{Style["Degree:", Bold], 
                                      Slider[Dynamic[n, (n = #;
                                                     cofs = PadRight[cofs, n + 1, 0];) &],
                                             {1, nmax, 1}],
                                      Style["Coefficients:", Bold], 
                                      Dynamic[Multicolumn[
                                              Array[Row[{Subscript["c", # - 1],
                                              Spacer[5],
                                              Slider[Dynamic[cofs[[#]]], {-2, 2}, 
                                                     ImageSize -> Small]}] &, n + 1],
                                              {9, Automatic}]]}], 
                   Spacer[20], 
                   Dynamic[Column[{Pane[
                   Row[{"f(x) = ", TraditionalForm[Expand[
                                                   FromDigits[Reverse[cofs], x]]]}]], 
                   Panel[Plot[FromDigits[Reverse[cofs], x], {x, -5, 5}, 
                              Axes -> None, Frame -> True]]}]]}]]]]
```

For instance:

[image: polynomial maker]

Comment: thx, silver medal for your answer.