# Can Manipulate controls be generated programmatically based on a (non-manipulated) variable?

Tags: manipulate

I would like to do something like this:

```
    nSines = 3;
    Manipulate[
            fn = {f1, f2, f3};
            Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[fn[[ii]] x], {ii, 1, Length[fn]}], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}],
            {{f1, 1}, 1, 6},
            {{f2, 2}, 1, 6},
            {{f3, 3}, 1, 6}
              ]
```

which generates the following output plot:

[image]

But I don't want to hard-code the number of `Manipulate` controls. So, I'd like to use just the variable `nSines` in the above example; it's currently unused.

Is there a way to do that? I haven't had any luck putting `Table` or `Sequence` as control arguments to `Manipulate`, but it's definitely possible I just missed the right syntax.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: related:[Manipulate with a variable number of sliders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! The answer is to use a combination of `Module`, `With`, and `Apply`'s (`@@`) to build things. Here's an example:

```
test[n_] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  With[{vars = Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]}, 
   Manipulate[ListPlot[vars, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], ##] & @@ 
   MapThread[{#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]} &, {vars, Table[{0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]}]]]
```

This should give a plot of `n` points which may be manipulated between 0 and 1.

`MapThread[{#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]} &, {vars, Table[{0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]}]` is what builds the "second part" of manipulate; `0` and `1` in `Table[{0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]` could be replaced with whatever algorithmically-computed ranges you wanted.

Using `##` in manipulate to represent a sequence of arguments, and stripping the `List` head off of the output of `MapThread` via `@@`, we get our usual `Manipulate` configuration.

The substitution of `vars` with the list of actual variables happens before evaluation via `With`. Each `x[i]` functions as a separate variable name here.

The problem now is that all the manipulate sliders have horrible `Module` names, like `x$34213[2]`, but this can be changed by altering `MapThread` appropriately!

So, in your case you'll want something like

```
Sines[n_] := 
 Module[{x},
  With[{vars = Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}]},
   Manipulate[
      Plot[
       Evaluate@Table[Sin[vars[[ii]] z], {ii, 1, n}],
       {z, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}],
      ##] & @@ 
   MapThread[{{#1, #2, #3}, #4[[1]], #4[[2]]} &,
     {vars, 
      Table[i, {i, 1, n}], (*defaults*)
      Table["f" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, n}], (*slider names*)
      Table[{1, 6}, {i, 1, n}] (*ranges*)}]
  ]]
```

Note that, for instance, you can also introduce the range for your sliders as a function argument, e.g. define `Sines[n_, frange:{_,_}:{1,6}]` by changing the defaults to, for example, `Table[frange[[1]] + i (frange[[2]] - frange[[1]])/n, {i, 0, n - 1}]`, and the ranges to `Table[frange, {i, 1, n}]`. (`Sines[4]` will still produce four sine waves with {1,6} as the default range under this definition.)

(Also, I'd recommend changing the default provided in the original one way or another, as for `n>6`, the sliders will start out-of-bounds.)

(Note also that we can also make things a bit more compact by using `Evaluate[Sin[# z] & /@ vars]` in `Plot` instead!)

Let me know if you're unfamiliar with any of the parts of Mathematica I've used and want to know how they work!

For fun, here's way too many.

[image: 20 sine waves of manipulable frequency]

Comment: THIS IS BEAUTIFUL!!!! Thank you so much for sharing, I love it! Here's a shot of the finished actual application in case you're interested :) :) :)

Comment: whoops: guess I can't screenshot in comment, so here's an imgur: https://imgur.com/a/Bx0EUDU

For the full application `f[#]&/@vars` definitely wouldn't have been enough, so thank you so much for your complete and creative answer!!

Comment: oh wow, it looks great!!! So glad I could help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want (as of yet, I'll come back to this), but it has a simplicity on which you might easily build:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  DynamicModule[{d},
     {Slider[Dynamic[d]],
      Dynamic[d],
      Dynamic[Plot[Sin[1 + d x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]]
      }] & /@ Range[nSines]
  ],
 {{nSines, 1}, 1, 5}
 ]
```

Which can give you output like the following when `nSines = 3`

[image]