# Parts[] of DynamicModule output

Tags: dynamic

I gave a partial answer to a question, [Can Manipulate controls be generated programmatically based on a (non-manipulated) variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233703/can-manipulate-controls-be-generated-programmatically-based-on-a-non-manipulate), which has led me to questions of my own.

Background:

The following code produces a pair of identical `Slider`s, where setting a value of 1 shows up in the other.

```
   {Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 1, 0.01}],
    Dynamic[d],
    Dynamic[Plot[Sin[1 + d x], {x, -10 \[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}]]
    } & /@ Range[2]
```

e.g.,

[image]

Wrapping the code in a `DynamicModule` gives you something different, the ability to set the `Slider`s independently (a possibly useful thing to do):

```
dm = DynamicModule[{d},
   {Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 1, 0.01}],
    Dynamic[d],
    Dynamic[Plot[Sin[1 + d x], {x, -10 \[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}]]
    }] & /@ Range[2]

{"Length", Length[dm]}
{"Dimensions", Dimensions[dm]}
TreeForm[dm]
```

[image]

[image]

I've added the `Length`, `Dimensions`, and `TreeForm` to better understand what the code actually produces.

Let's explore this a bit more:

```
dm[[1]]
Length[%]
```

Note, I set the `Slider` to `0.69` after executing the code.

[image]

And now I try to extract the `Parts` of the expression:

```
dm[[1, 1]]
dm[[1, 2]]
dm[[1, 3]]
```

[image]

This seems a bit strange.
I would have expected that I would get the 3 `Part`s of `dm[[1]]` in order, e.g:

```
Slider
Value
Plot
```

So, some questions:

1. Can someone explain this?  The `Part`s of `dm[[1]]` don't appear to behave as one would expect.
2. Does a way exist to access the current state of the 2 `Plot`s in `dm`, and for instance `Show` them together?
3. Does the `TreeForm` give us any insight into how to do access `Part`s of such expressions?

I realize that these questions might resemble something akin to arcane [chess problems](https://www.chess.com/terms/chess-problems), with not much real world application, but I hope that answers could give some additional working insight into these structures.

Comment: It looks to me like you are getting the three parts of the first `DynamicModule`: `List[d]`, another `List`, and a `DelayedRule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- `DynamicModule` does not disappear like `Module`. After initial evaluation of content it stays inert and will be used when it is sent as an output to produce DynamicModuleBox which governs scoping within your gui.

```
dm[[1]] // InputForm
```

```
DynamicModule[
  {d}, 
  {Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 1, 0.01}], Dynamic[d], Dynamic[Plot[Sin[1 + d*x], {x, -10*Pi, 10*Pi}]]}, 
  DynamicModuleValues :> {}
]
```

This is `dm[[1]]` and it has two arguments and one option which means you will get length `3`.

2- `dm` is just an expression as any other, `Table[dm, {10}]` contains 10 independent copies of it. Each generated GUI will be independent. If you want to access values from inside most often you will need to do this from inside e.g.:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Slider @ Dynamic[x, (notScopedX = x = # )&]
```

Now you can use `Dynamic @ notScopedX` somewhere else.

3- Sure it does, just like the `InputForm` for example. Your tree form says you can access the first slider with `dm[[1, 2, 1]]`. But this is a copy of what was used to generate GUI earlier/later.

Let me know if anything is not clear.