Programmatically establishing controllers for Manipulate inside a module
I am trying to create a module that allows users to cycle lists to look for a pattern and need a way to programmatically establish the number of controllers depending on the number of lists being used. As a small example, I am trying to do something like this:
 testModule[___] := 
 Module[{disks = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", 
      "i"}}},
  Manipulate[
   Row[{Column[RotateRight[disks[[1]], Disk1], Spacings -> 1],
     Column[RotateRight[disks[[2]],  Disk2], Spacings -> 1],
     Column[RotateRight[disks[[3]], Disk3], Spacings -> 1]}],
   {{Disk1, 0}, -3, 3, 1},
   {{Disk2, 0}, -3, 3, 1},
   {{Disk3, 0}, -3, 3, 1}]]

What I would like to do is be able to set up the controller command programmatically because there are in some examples 32 lists (called disks) but I am also wanting a way to make the number of lists variable.
Looking through the StackExchange, I think it is a some combination of using With and setting the initial values, but I cannot get it to work.

At the end of this answer there is an approach similar to my answer taken from the documentation for Manipulate[]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1200

I've done it like this, with an array controlled by a set of sliders in the case of a matrix. Here all we need is a vector for the rotations.
test // ClearAll;
test[disks_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{$rot = Table[0, Length@disks], (* need to initialize rot to be a vector *)
     dim = Dimensions@disks},
   Manipulate[
    Grid[Transpose@MapThread[RotateRight, {disks, rot}]],
    {{rot, $rot, "rotate"}, (* the initial value is the vector $rot *)
     Row[Table[With[{i = i}, (* inject the Part index *)
         Labeled[VerticalSlider[
           Dynamic@rot[[i]], (* each slider changes one part *)
           {-Last@dim + 1, Last@dim - 1, 1}, 
           ImageSize -> Small], Style[i, Italic]]
         ], {i, First@dim}]
       ] &}
    ]
   ];

SeedRandom[0];
disks = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 4];
disks = ReplacePart[#, 
    RandomInteger[{1, 4}] -> Style["X", Magenta]] & /@ disks


test[disks]



You CAN programmatically create controls for Manipulate, but it's actually more involved that it would be to just change your model. I can show you later if you want, but what you might try in the meantime is something like this:
DiskData[diskCount_, diskLength_] := 
  ArrayReshape[Alphabet[], {diskCount, diskLength}, Alphabet[]];
DiskManipulate[diskCount_, diskLength_] :=
  Module[
    {offsets = ConstantArray[0, diskCount],
     currentDisk = 1,
     initData = DiskData[diskCount, diskLength]},
    Manipulate[
      offsets[[currentDisk]] = offset;
      currentDisk = disk;
      offset = offsets[[disk]];
      TableForm[Transpose[MapThread[RotateRight, {initData, offsets}]]],
      {{disk, 1}, Range[diskCount]},
      {{offset, 0}, -diskLength, diskLength, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]

Try it with
DiskManipulate[3, 5]



It throws several red flags when I enter it, but it appears to work.
